# Brezis Exercise 3.27 Extension.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

> Let $E$ be a separable Banach space with norm $\|\cdot\|$. The dual norm on $E^*$ is also denoted $\|\cdot\|$.
>
> Let $(a_n) \subset B_E$ be a dense subset of $B_E$ with respect to the strong topology.
>
> Let $(b_n) \subset B_{E^*}$ be a countable subset of $B_{E^*}$that is dense in $B_{E^*}$ for the $\text{weak}^*$ topology $\sigma(E^*, E)$.
>
> Given $f \in E^*$, set$$\|f\|_1 = \left\{\|f\|^2 + \sum_{n = 1}^\infty |\langle f, a_n\rangle|^2\right\}^{1\over2}.$$Given $x \in E$, set$$\|x\|_2 = \left\{\|x\|_1^2 + \sum_{n = 1}^\infty {1\over{2^n}}|\langle b_n, x\rangle|^2\right\}^{1\over2},$$where $\|x\|_1 = \sup_{\|f\|_1 \le 1} \langle f, x\rangle$.

Why does the fact that the dual norm of $\|\cdot\|_2$ is strictly convex follow from results in Problem 4 in the textbook?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: In the text : What are $\phi^*, \theta^*$  etc.?

Comment: @user254665. It *could* be the [convex conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_conjugate) of $\phi$ or $\theta$.

Comment: A small comment: I don't think the stated definition of $\Vert f \Vert_1$ is correct, because, as stated, $f\neq 0\Rightarrow\Vert f \Vert_1=+\infty$. Indeed, if $f\neq 0$, then $\Vert f\Vert > 0$, which implies there is a subsequence $(a_{k_n})_n$ s.t. $\vert \langle f,a_{k_n}\rangle \vert \to \Vert f\Vert$, which implies 
$$
\sum_{n}\vert\langle f,a_n\rangle\vert^2=+\infty
$$

Comment: @NateRiver. I agree,